# Apps script - export JSON-file from spreadsheet with replacement old file

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need a little help with my script, I wrote by help from internet.

I export data from spreadsheet to json-file and save it on google-drive, but every new file doesn't replace old file. Script creates new file with ending at name of new file (1), (2) etc:

- exp_planning.json - this file I need
- exp_planning(1).json - this file and other with  I not need

Be happy for your help! Thank you, friends!))

```js
function convertSheet2JsonText(sheet) {
  // first line(title)
  var colStartIndex = 1;
  var rowNum = 1;
  var firstRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 15);
  var firstRowValues = firstRange.getValues();
  var titleColumns = firstRowValues[0];

  // after the second line(data)
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var rowValues = [];
  for(var rowIndex = 2; rowIndex <= lastRow; rowIndex ++ ) {
    var strRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rowIndex, 1).getValue();

    if(strRange != "") {
      var colStartIndex = 1;
      var rowNum = 1;
      var range = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, colStartIndex, rowNum, 15);
      var values = range.getValues();
      rowValues.push(values[0]);
    }
  }

  // create json
  var jsonArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i<rowValues.length; i++) {
    var line = rowValues[i];
    var json = new Object();

    for(var j=0; j<titleColumns.length; j++) {
      json[titleColumns[j]] = line[j];
    }
    jsonArray.push(json);
  }
  //return jsonArray;
  Logger.log(jsonArray);

  var blob,file,fileSets,obj;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('JSON_EXPFILES').next();
    fileSets = {
      title: 'exp_planning.json',
      mimeType: 'application/json',
      "parents": [
        {
          "id": folder.getId(),
          "kind": "drive#parentReference"
        }
      ]
    };

  blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(jsonArray), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
  file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s, type: %s', file.id, file.fileSize, file.mimeType);
}

function doGet() {

  var sheetName = "для ТК";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var json = convertSheet2JsonText(sheet);

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I found one way with deleting old file before creating new...

```js
  var allFiles = folder.getFilesByName(fileSets.title);

  while (allFiles.hasNext()) {
    file = allFiles.next();
    file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  }
```

but may be there is anything else about replacement old file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When you create a new file of `exp_planning.json` in the specific folder, you want to remove the existing files, which are the same filename, in the specific folder. And then, you want to create new file to the folder.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the file of `exp_planning.json` is created to the specific folder using `Drive.Files.insert()`. In this case, the files with the same filename are created. So, it is required to check the existing files and create the new file. But, when I saw the script of `I found one way with deleting old file before creating new...`, `removeFile` of Class Folder is used. This had been used for removing the given file from the current folder. In the current stage, this method was deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removefilechild)
- When you want to remove the file, you can use `setTrashed` of Class File or the method of "Files: delete" in Drive API.
- And, at `blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(jsonArray), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");`, when you want to give the mimeType, please use `application/json`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('JSON_EXPFILES').next();
  fileSets = {
    title: 'exp_planning.json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": folder.getId(),
        "kind": "drive#parentReference"
      }
    ]
  };

blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(jsonArray), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
```

To:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('JSON_EXPFILES').next();
var filename = 'exp_planning.json';
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  files.next().setTrashed(true);
}
// Drive.Files.emptyTrash();  // If you want to empty the trash box, you can also use this. But when you use this, please be careful this.
fileSets = {
  title: filename,
  mimeType: 'application/json',
  "parents": [
    {
      "id": folder.getId(),
      "kind": "drive#parentReference"
    }
  ]
};
blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(jsonArray), 'application/json');
file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
```

- If you want to empty the trash box, you can also use `Drive.Files.emptyTrash()`. But when you use this, please be careful this.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that `jsonArray` is the correct value you expect. Please be careful this.
- When you want to overwrite the existing file of `exp_planning.json`, please modify above script of "From:" as follows. In this modification, when the file is existnig, the file is overwritten by `blob` using the method of "Files: update". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)

  ```
    var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('JSON_EXPFILES').next();
    var filename = 'exp_planning.json';
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
    blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(jsonArray), 'application/json');
    if (files.hasNext()) {
      file = Drive.Files.update({}, files.next().getId(), blob);
      // or DriveApp.getFileById(files.next().getId()).setContent(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
    } else {
      fileSets = {
        title: filename,
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        "parents": [
          {
            "id": folder.getId(),
            "kind": "drive#parentReference"
          }
        ]
      };
      file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [setTrashed(trashed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)

Comment: Thank you very much for help. It really works!))) it is useful for me to comprehend new things)

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.